# Incorrectly Displaying Tags at Tags Archives Page

Tags: wordpress

i'm using wp job manager and tags addon, i face incorrectly display in tags archives page after last theme and plugins update

when i go to a tag keyword like ( https://www.wzufa.com/job-tag/saudi-arabia/ for example) all jobs in Saudi Arabia tag should displayed, but it appears for second and then disappear.

but it working great if it selected by click from (Filter by tag) at search page (https://www.wzufa.com/browse-jobs/) I’d like to fix this to browse all keywords

i try to disable some suspected plugins but still tags keyword archive not working

Comment: After several try to find the file that has the problem i got the problem it's come from workscout-ajax-filters.min.js file is here is that: bit.ly/2FDZLFJ

Is there a conflict between him and tags plugin?

Comment: any one can help please